# radius of convergence $\sum \left(\frac {n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}z^{kn}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the radius of convergence of the series where $k$ being the constant.
$$\sum  \left(\frac {n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}z^{kn}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the [root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) we have

$$\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac {n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}|z|^{kn}}=\left(\frac {n+1}{n}\right)^{n}|z|^{k}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}e|z|^k<1\iff |z|<e^{-1/k}$$
so
$$R=e^{-1/k}$$

Comment: yes..thank you..

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: This series coverges for $<1$ atlast.. that is why you are concluding this.. Am I right?@sami

Comment: Yes, see the link in my answer.